# docker-entrypoint.sh is being ignored

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

The console logs `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables` during the build of the Docker container (see full log below). What could be the case for this considering I have the following code:

**File overview**

### [image: overview of files]

**users.sql**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    email text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    entries BEGINT DEFAULT 0,
    joined TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

COMMIT;
```

**deploy_schemas.sql**

```
-- Deploy fresh database tables
\i '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/users.sql'
\i '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/login.sql'
```

**Dockerfile (in postgres folder)**
        FROM postgres:12.2

```
    ADD /tables/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/
    ADD deploy_schemas.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/
**docker-compose.yml**
version: "3.3"

services:

    # Backend API
    smart-brain-app:
        container_name: backend
        # image: mode:14.2.0
        build: ./
        command: npm start
        working_dir: /usr/src/smart-brain-api
        environment:
            POSTGRES_URI: postgres://postgres:1212@postgres:5431/smart-brain-api-db
        links:
            - postgres
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/smart-brain-api

    # Postgres
    postgres:
        build: ./postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1212
            POSTGRES_DB: smart-brain-api-db
            POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
        ports:
            - "5431:5432"
```

**Dockerfile**
    FROM node:14.2.0

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/smart-brain-api

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install | npm audit fix

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

**Complete Log**

```
Creating smart-brain-api_postgres_1 ... done
Creating backend                    ... done
Attaching to smart-brain-api_postgres_1, backend
postgres_1         | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres_1         | This user must also own the server process.       
postgres_1         | 
postgres_1         | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres_1         | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres_1         | The default text search configuration will be set 
to "english".
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres_1         | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres_1         | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres_1         | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres_1         | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres_1         | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgres_1         | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres_1         | running bootstrap script ... ok
backend            | 
backend            | > node@1.0.0 start /usr/src/smart-brain-api       
backend            | > npx nodemon server.js
backend            |
postgres_1         | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgres_1         | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres_1         | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgres_1         | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile 
start
postgres_1         | 
postgres_1         | waiting for server to start....2020-05-10 01:31:31.548 UTC [46] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) 
on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit 
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.549 UTC [46] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.565 UTC [47] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-05-10 01:31:31 UTC
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.569 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1         |  done
postgres_1         | server started
postgres_1         | CREATE DATABASE
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.772 UTC [46] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres_1         | waiting for server to shut down....2020-05-10 01:31:31.774 UTC [46] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.775 UTC [46] LOG:  background 
worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 53) exited with exit code 1 
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.778 UTC [48] LOG:  shutting down
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.791 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres_1         |  done
postgres_1         | server stopped
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start 
up.
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.884 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.884 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.884 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.894 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.910 UTC [64] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-05-10 01:31:31 UTC
postgres_1         | 2020-05-10 01:31:31.914 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: You need to put the files directly in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, not in a subdirectory.

Comment: What do you mean?